# Deferred execution value unchanged

Tags: c#, entity-framework, deferred-execution

Say I have `IQueryable<Car> cars`.

I iterate it such as:

```
foreach (Car c in cars)
{
    c.Doors = 2;
}
```

Why does `c.Doors` contain the original value after the foreach, instead of the changed value?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I know if I convert it to a List before I enumerate, I get the correct results.

Comment: Either the implementation of IQueryable<Car> generates a new set on each iteration or the setter of Car.Doors is 'broken'. Please show us where IQuerable<Car> is created

Comment: IQueryable<Car> is the result of a Linq to Entities query. The setter is fine because in the Linq query, I can assign the value to the property Doors.

Comment: Enumerators can be used to read the data in the collection, but they cannot be used to modify the underlying collection.

Comment: @vulkanino - In this case the collection is not modified, just the items within the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated that IQueryable is the result of a linq to entities query which is not a correct statement. MyDatabaseContext.Cars.Where(x => x.Name == "Test") returns a IQueryable which on iteration perfoms a query on the database. (Iteration is when you perform a foreach over it). So it doesnt contain the result set yet, just the query.

looping twice over cars generates 2 identical queries to the database and returns 2 identical result sets. If you want to preserve the data. you need to call ToArray or ToList or after manipulation, perform a save of the changes before you iterate again.

Comment: Maybe it was poor phrasing on my part, but I know the IQueryable by itself doesn't execute the query. So, when I iterate it the query is executed once. If I do a ToList() after the iteration, the query will be executed again. Right?

Comment: Correct, ToList internally iterates the source as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over an `IQueryable` retrieves the result set from the database as it goes, as I'm sure you know. What I've observed in this and other situations is that this result is not cached, so you'll often find that iterating over the `IQueryable` again will actually run the query again, thus your modifications aren't preserved because you're getting a new result set which was never affected by that code.

The reason it works when you call `ToList()` first and iterate over the result of that is because `ToList()` retrieves and materialises the entire result set, which is then no longer linked to the database content and is really just a copy of what the database returned.

The only way to be sure your changes will stick is to operate on the local copy of the data, i.e. lift it out of `IQueryable` land. This can be as simple as saving an `IEnumerable` of the result set (i.e. the result of `ToEnumerable()`), which will then return the same result set each time you enumerate it, but unlike `ToList()` it won't cause evaluation immediately.